# Find four positive integers having more than $100$ divisors

Tags: number-theory

> Find four positive integers each not exceeding $70000$ and each having more than $100$ divisors.

Since we are trying to maximize divisors and minimize value, we assume that $n = 2^{\alpha_1} 3^{\alpha_2} \cdots$ has $\alpha_1 \geq \alpha_2 \geq \cdots.$ Now we do casework.

How do we do the casework since there seem to be so many cases?

Comment: different divisors ? even if it was 2 only , $2^{100}$ > 70000

Comment: @user1952009 Yes you can: $2^2 \cdot 3^2 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11$.

Comment: any divisors, not only primary , ok ... interesting

Comment: wait ok number of divisors is more complicated than sum of divisors

Comment: $$2^6\cdot 3^3\cdot 5\cdot 7 = 60480$$ has $7\cdot 4\cdot 2\cdot 2=112$ divisors, for instance.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Right, I would like to know a method for finding these.

Comment: @user19405892: trial and error works pretty fine here.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio There is no other method?

Comment: Improved brute force: you may compute the number of divisors of every number in the range $[100,70000]$ whose prime divisors belong to the set $\{2,3,5,7,11,13\}$: that requires at most one second of CPU time.

Comment: Note that if a number has prime decomposition $p_1^{a_1} p_2^{a_2} \ldots p_k^{a_k}$, the number of divisors is the number of integer vectors $(b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_k)$ such that $0 \leq b_i \leq a_i$. So, you have $a_1 a_2 \ldots a_k$ divisors for that number.

Comment: I think you have $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$.

Comment: Are you trying to write a program or find the answer by hand? If you are programming, then you can adapt the sieve of Eratosthenes algorithm to get a reasonably efficient algorithm that will give the number of divisors of every number up to a given limit.

Comment: @RobArthan I am trying to write a mathematical proof to find all such numbers.

Comment: heuristic by hand is possible too

Comment: @RobArthan, Mathematica needs less than one second to give me the output of "Select[Range[70000], Length[Divisors[#]] >= 100 &]".

Comment: @Santiago: that's not very interesting, if you're interested in designing a really fast algorithm with a good estimate on the performance. However, the OP is not interested in that (or Mathematica).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Answer (score 2):

It's just a hand heuristic which is possible because the limits of the puzzle ...

Having the 7 first primes power 1 is enough to get $2^7 > 100$ factors

Their product is too high : $2.3.5.7.11.13.17 = 510510$ which is $> 70000$

Let's replace 17 by 16 = $2^4$ : $2^4 .3.5.7.11.13 = 240240$ // too high

idem with 13 by 8 = $2^3$ : $2^7 .3.5.7.11 = 147840$ // too high

Let's replace 4 by 3 : $2^5 .3^2 .5.7.11 = 110880$ // too high

let's reduce the power of 2 by 1 :

**$2^4 .3^2 .5.7.11 = 55440$**

**factors : $5 . 3 . 2^3 = 120$** // ok , first result !

let's replace 11 par 13 too see if it is in the bounds

**$2^4 .3^2 .5.7.13 = 65520$**

**factors : $5 . 3 . 2^3 = 120$** // ok

play again between 2 and 5

**$2^2 . 3^2 .5^2 .7.11 = 69300$ // ok**

**factors : $3 . 3 . 3 . 2 . 2 = 104$**

Need a last one , let's try without 11 and 13

**$2^6 . 3^3 . 5. 7 = 60480$** // ok
factors : $7. 4. 2. 2 = 112$

Answer (score 1):

I'd love to just add it as a comment, but 50400 (108 divisors), 55440 (112 divisors), 60480 (120 divisors), 65520 (112 divisors), and 69300 (108 divisors) suit the numbers you are looking for.

Comment: How did you come up with these numbers?

Comment: Brute force, sorry. I'm trying to see if I can come up with some elegant method.

Comment: It's nice to add that there are no other numbers below 70 000 having that many divisors. Exactly 100 numbers divide 45360, by the way.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

Comment: Edit your answer, dear friend: 55400 has only $24$ divisors.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried here to present a method for solving the problem. It is somewhat tedious but I could not find anything better (excepting, of course, brute force, especially if done with a calculator or a program).

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ the numbers. Of the two restrictions, $x_i\lt 70000$ and the name of divisors is greater than $100$, the second is the strongest:  it depends on the exponents of the prime factors of $x_i$. From the known number $D$ of divisors of an integer $n$ (I mean $\prod p_i^{n_i}\Rightarrow D=\prod (n_i+1)$)  and because of the bound $70000$  for $x_i$ it is clear that we need small primes with some large  exponents.

We notice first
$$A=70000=2^4\cdot5^4\cdot7\\2^{16}\lt A\lt2^{17}\\3^{10}\lt A\lt 3^{11}\\5^6\lt A\lt 5^7\\7^5\lt A\lt7^6\\11^4\lt A\lt11^5\\13^4\lt A\lt13^5\\17^3\lt A\lt17^4$$ Discarding of $17$, then of larger primes, we do as follows: $$\boxed{17}$$
$$17^3\cdot2^4\gt A\Rightarrow\text{ only $16$ divisors }\\17^2\cdot2^8\gt A\Rightarrow\text{ only $27$ divisors }\\17^2\cdot2^5\cdot3^2\gt A\Rightarrow\text{ only $54$ divisors }\\17\cdot2^a3^b\gt A\Rightarrow\text{ less of $100$ divisors } $$
$$\boxed{13}$$ 
$$13^4\cdot2^2\gt A \Rightarrow\text{ only $15$ divisors }$$ $$13^3\text { gives a factor } 4\text{ for }  D \text { so if }
  13^3\cdot2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c\text{ one needs }(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)\gt 25$$
Similarly $13^2$ can be ruled out but for $13$ one has $13\cdot2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c$ for which $$13\cdot2^5\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot7\gt A\gt 13\cdot2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot7\text{ and } 2\cdot5\cdot3\cdot2\cdot2\gt 100$$ Thus the first example $\color{red}{13\cdot2^4\cdot 3^2\cdot 5\cdot7=65520}$
$$\boxed{11}$$
$11^4\cdot2^3\gt A$ would give $D=20$ and $11^3\cdot2^6\gt A$ would give $D=28$ hence no solution of the form $11^4\cdot 2^a$ nor $11^3\cdot 2^a$ and similarly with $11^a\cdot p^b$ for $p=3,5,7$ with $a=4,3$.

For $11^i,\space i=1,2$ one has  $11^i\cdot2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c\cdot7^d$, with exponents no negative, one needs $$\begin{cases}11^i\cdot2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c\cdot7^d\lt A\\(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\gt 34\text{ for } i=2\text{ and }\gt 50\text{ for } i=1\end{cases}$$ 
Some care gives no solution for $11^2$ and for $i=1$, the product $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)=(3)(3)(3)(2)=54$ gives the second solution $\color{red}{11\cdot2^2\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot7=69300}$ and the product $(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)=(5)(3)(2)(2)=60$ gives a third solution $\color{red}{11\cdot2^4\cdot3^2\cdot5\cdot7=55440}$
$$\boxed{2,3,5,7}$$  One has to solve
$$\begin{cases}2^a\cdot 3^b\cdot 5^c\cdot7^d\lt A\\(a+1)(b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\gt 100 \end{cases}$$
Taking into account (from the beginning) to facilitate calculations  $$A=70000=2^4\cdot5^4\cdot7\\2^{16}\lt A\lt2^{17}\\3^{10}\lt A\lt 3^{11}\\5^6\lt A\lt 5^7\\7^5\lt A\lt7^6$$  and paying careful attention we have $$2^6\cdot3^b\cdot5^c\cdot7^d$$
$$2^6\cdot3^b\cdot5^c\cdot7^d\Rightarrow (b+1)(c+1)(d+1)\gt 14$$ Since $2^6\cdot7^4\gt A, 2^6\cdot5^5\gt A$ and $2^6\cdot3^7\gt A$ given $D=35,42,56$ respectively, there are not solutions with $2^6$ multiplied by a power of a prime factors in $\{3,5,7\}$. Similarly with three prime factors and finally we obtain after careful (*and easy*) calculation a fourth and a fifth solution and not more. One has $\color{red}{2^6\cdot3^3\cdot5\cdot7=60480 }$ and $\color{red}{2^5\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdot7=50400 }$

Answer (score 0):

Put $n=\prod_{i=1}^{n}p_i^{\alpha_i}$, the factorization of n in primes.

Every divisor have the same form, with different coefficents. Then, $n$ has $\prod_{i=1}^{n}(\alpha_i+1)$ divisors.

Now, you can play with this